# Заполнение navigation Tab в Mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Учусь делать интернет магазин. Ситуация следующая: хочу реализовать что-то подобное как на картинке:

[image: Картинка]

Вопрос следующий: каким образом мне заполнять эти табы, товаров же будет много очень, и как под каждый товар заполнять инфу? Ну, допустим описание я вытяну с БД, это не проблема, а как тогда быть с характеристиками для каждой товара (размер, цвет и т.п.)? Создавать поля в БД под каждую характеристику? Так это может очень много полей получиться. Как тогда поступить в таком случае?